# libpangox-1.0.so.0:i386 for Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, 64-bit, 32-bit, pango

I need `libpangox-1.0-0:i386` to build a package under Ubuntu 20.04LTS, but it is not currently available.
I have `libpangox-1.0-0` in my system.

The 32 bit version is available for 19.10 and below
at
https://pkgs.org/download/libpangox-1.0-0
https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/19.10/ubuntu-universe-i386/libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5build1_i386.deb.html

1. **What are alternative ways to obtain this?**
2. If I get the `.deb` file for 19.10 and run `sudo gdebi libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5build1_i386.deb`,
   **does it simply store files listed under "Files" in the web page, without any further changes to the system other than registering the package for `dpkg`?**

   **Can I give it a shot, try if it works, and if not simply remove the package?**
   (there might be some issues, since files under `/usr/share/doc/libpangox-1.0-0`, even if only documentation, are shared among 32 bit and 64 bit versions).
   Note that the files in the package are only the `so` and a soft link to it, 
   `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangox-1.0.so.0`
   and 
   `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangox-1.0.so.0.0.0`.

Notes:
I never built something like this from source.

**EDIT**:

To avoid messing with `dpkg`, as a first attempt I expanded the `.deb` file, and copied the `so` and soft link by hand into  `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`.
Then

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu"
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary
...
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found for /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangox-1.0.so.0 (used by debian/iscan/usr/bin/iscan)
Hint: check if the library actually comes from a package.
```

which led me to trying three workarounds at the same time:

1. Adding to `debian/rules`

```
    override_dh_shlibdeps:
    (tab)   dh_shlibdeps --dpkg-shlibdeps-params=--ignore-missing-info
```

2. `$ export DEB_DH_SHLIBDEPS_ARGS_ALL=--dpkg-shlibdeps-params=--ignore-missing-info`
3. `$ export DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck`

None of this removed the error above.

**EDIT #2**.

Trying to build the library, I got the error

```
$ debuild -a i386
...
dpkg-deb: building package 'libpangox-1.0-dev' in '../libpangox-1.0-dev_0.0.2-5ubuntu1_i386.deb'.
 dpkg-genbuildinfo
 dpkg-genchanges  >../pangox-compat_0.0.2-5ubuntu1_i386.changes
dpkg-genchanges: info: not including original source code in upload
 dpkg-source --after-build .
dpkg-source: info: using options from pangox-compat-0.0.2/debian/source/options: --compression=xz
dpkg-buildpackage: info: binary and diff upload (original source NOT included)
debuild: fatal error at line 1062:
can't open pangox-compat_0.0.2-5ubuntu1_amd64.changes for reading: No such file or directory
```

Related:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238134/dpkg-shlibdeps-error-no-dependency-information-found-for

https://linux.debian.user.narkive.com/tVuR0mKc/package-shared-library-with-application

https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity-nginx/issues/16

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg-shlibdeps.1.html

https://ubuntu.com/blog/statement-on-32-bit-i386-packages-for-ubuntu-19-10-and-20-04-lts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you need to enable all *deb-src* (Source Code) repositories using *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`). Then confirm refreshing package lists or run `sudo apt-get update` manually.

Then get the source code and compile it for 32-bit with command below

```
# get build tools
sudo apt-get install devscripts gcc-i686-linux-gnu
# get build dependencies for 32-bit (i386) architecture
sudo apt-get build-dep -a i386 libpangox-1.0-0

# get source
cd ~/Downloads
apt-get source libpangox-1.0-0
cd pangox-compat-0.0.2

# compile source for i386
debuild -a i386
```

and finally install compiled packages with

```
sudo apt-get install ../libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5ubuntu1_i386.deb  ../libpangox-1.0-dev_0.0.2-5ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and post feedback.
In the meantime, please check edited OP. If you have any comment, I would be glad to try.

Comment: Trying to build the package I got an error I could not solve so far. Please see EDIT #2.

Comment: You can ignore error message about .changes file, the debs are compiled.

Comment: Great, it worked!

Answer (score 10):

I too had this issue of missing libpangox-1.0.so.0 on Ubuntu 21.04.

I was able to work around this issue by creating a softlink to the pangoxft module to get this working, by executing this command.

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoxft-1.0.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangox-1.0.so.0`

Hope this helps.